# Cent OS 6 clock 3 minutes 35 seconds in the future

Tags: centos6, linode, time, clock-synchronization

I run Cent os 6 64 bit on linode.

**server (incorrect):**

> date
>       Thu Aug 29 11:41:00 BST 2013

**client (correct):**

> date
>       Thu Aug 29 11:37:25 BST 2013

As you can see the server clock is in the future.

so far I have ensured the server is running at GMT time, by doing

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London /etc/localtime
```

but no joy, and by installing NPT, which is suggested by Linode.

215 seconds seems like its not a GMT time issue, as I would expect that to be likes of multiples of 1 hour in future/past.

Any tips?

Comment: Installing ntp is not enough, you need to configure and start ntpd or just use `ntpdate pool.ntp.org` for a one-time clock sync

Comment: thanks, I did ntpdate pool.ntp.org and that solved! if you post an answer I shall accept.

Comment: `ntpdate` is useful for a one-time update but the answer of @dsumsky is better in your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would either verify that the server time is synchronized with XEN host

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/xen/independent_wallclock
```

or I would disable this method and configure standalone time synchronisation via NTP

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/xen/independent_wallclock

yum install ntp
service ntpd start
chkconfig ntpd on
```

Put this line to /etc/sysctl.conf to make wallclock independent persistent

```
xen.independent_wallclock = 0
```

Comment: Tip: a clock sync is not instant with ntpd, it will sync smoothly. You can use ntpdate before starting ntpd if you need a first "direct" sync

Answer (score 0):

to check server time

```
# date
```

check connectivity to sync servers and look for the time difference:

```
# ntpdate -q 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org
```

synchronize time manually with servers:

```
# ntpdate 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org 1.rhel.pool.ntp.org
```

if you want to check system time on boot:

```
# chkconfig ntpdate on
```

more info:
https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-Date_and_Time_Configuration-Command_Line_Configuration-Network_Time_Protocol.html